# How do I disable/enable unchecked input checkboxes - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several rows of checkboxes in a table. When one input is checked, I need to disable the other two in the same table row.  However, if I come back and uncheck the input, I need to set disabled to false for the other two.

```
<table>
        <tr class="row1"><td>Row 1</td><td><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="">Row 1 Column 1</td><td><input value="2" type="checkbox" name="">Row 1 Column 2</td><td><input value="3" type="checkbox" name="">Row 1 Column 3</td></tr>

        <tr class="row2"><td>Row 2</td><td><input type="checkbox" name=""></td><td><input type="checkbox" name=""></td><td><input type="checkbox" name=""></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `check` one `checked=true` you want others to be disabled `disabled=true` and vice versa. So the same state `true/false` of the one (checked) controls state of the others.

With that established, the rest of the code is straight-forward, find the parent `tr` then all the `checkbox` elements, but not `this`, and set their `disabled` property to [boolean] value of `checked`.

```
$(function() {
   $(':checkbox').on('change',function() {
        var checked = this.checked;
        $(this).closest('tr').find(':checkbox').not(this).prop('disabled',checked);
    });
});
```

[**WORKING JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/EyRkm/)

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  Now I will try to make sense of it so I can learn.

Comment: Glad I could help. Let me add some explanation for yours and other's reference.